# PHP update() MySQL database not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, web

I am working on a quiz that asks the user for demographic information at the end, but I am having some issue correctly populating the table with the information that I gather.

The following code is a part of my databaseAdapator.php file. The first, initUser(), sets up a user entry in my database and initializes everything to 0 - this is happening/I can see these values in MySQL.

udpateUser() is where I am having issues. The page that calls it (addUser.php) has all of the information that the function needs, but when I call it there is no change in the database.

Essentially, I want to execute the following command:

```
update users set age=11, gender="Male", height_cm=2 where user_id=95;
```

My code

```
public function initUser($age, $gender, $height, $weight, $ip){
    //create new dummy user
    $stmt = $this->DB->prepare("Insert into users values(null, :age, :gender, :height, :weight, :ip)");
    $stmt->bindParam('age', $age);
    $stmt->bindParam('gender', $gender);
    $stmt->bindParam('height', $height);
    $stmt->bindParam('weight', $weight);
    $stmt->bindParam('ip', $ip);
    $stmt->execute();

    //select last insert ID
    $stmt = $this->DB->prepare("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() from users");
    $stmt->execute();
    $userId = $stmt->fetch();
    return $userId[0];
}


public function updateUser($user, $age, $gender, $height, $weight){
    //edit the information for a user after demographics page
    $stmt = $this->DB->prepare("UPDATE users SET age=:age, gender=:gender, height_cm=:height, weight_kg=:weight WHERE user_id=:user");
    $stmt->bindParam('age', $age);
    $stmt->bindParam('gender', $gender);
    $stmt->bindParam('height', $height);
    $stmt->bindParam('weight', $weight);
    $stmt->bindParam('user', $user);
    $stmt->execute();

    return $user;
}
```

Here is addUser.php, the page calling the function. I know this is horrendous practice (sorry!), I'm trying to get the database adaptor working correctly for the time being, and I have checked all the variables manually - they are all valid and non-null.

```
<?php
require_once("./databaseAdaptor.php");
$user = $_GET["user"];

$age = $_POST["Age"];
$gender = $_POST["Gender"];
$height_in = $_POST['in'];
$height_ft = $_POST['ft'];
$height = 2.54 * (($height_ft * 12) + $height_in);
$weight = $_POST['lbs'];


$userId = $myDatabaseFunctions->updateUser($user, $age, $gender, $height, $weight);
?>
```

EDIT: 
Here is where I call initUser.php

```
<?php
require_once("./databaseAdaptor.php");

$userId = $myDatabaseFunctions->initUser(0, null, 0, 0,  0);
?>

<form name='fr' action='quiz.php' method='POST'>
        <input type='hidden' name='user' value='<?=$userId?>'>
        <input type="submit" />
</form>


<script type='text/javascript'>
document.fr.submit();
</script>
```

Here is demographic.php, which includes the form that gathers information for addUser.php. The first form that goes to quiz.php asks the user a series of questions, when they reach the end it sends them here. Looking in the database, their answers are being recorded, and the initialization appears to be happening "correctly". The only thing I have been unsuccessful at doing is updating the users information at the tail end of the quiz.

```html
<?php
require_once("./databaseAdaptor.php");

$page = '0';

if( isset($_GET["user"])) {
        $user = $_GET["user"];
} else {
        echo "error";
$page = '1';
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML5>
<html lang="en">

<body bgcolor="#0000">
<font color="white">

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript" />
    <title>FOOD CALORIES</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>

<body>

    <div>
        <h4><a href="index.html">Calorie4Food</a></h4>
    </div>
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
        <center>



                        <form  method="post" action="./addUser.php?user=<?php echo $user?>" onsubmit="checkform()">
<h6>
                        <!-- Age Button -->
                <fieldset id="Age" >
                        Please Select Age: <br>
                        <input type="radio" value="10" name="Age" > 10<br>
                        <input type="radio" value="20" name="Age"> 11 - 20<br>
                        <input type="radio" value="30" name="Age"> 21 - 30<br>
                        <input type="radio" value="40" name="Age"> 31 - 40<br>
                        <input type="radio" value="50" name="Age"> 41 - 50<br>
                        <input type="radio" value="60" name="Age"> 51 - 60<br>
                        <input type="radio" value="60" name="Age">  > 60<br>
                </fieldset>

                        <!-- Gender Button -->
                        <fieldset id="Gender" >
                                Please Select Gender: <br>
                        <input type="radio" value="Male" name="Gender" > Male <br>
                        <input type="radio" value="Female" name="Gender"> Female <br>
                        <input type="radio" value="Other" name="Gender"> Other <br>
                        </fieldset>

                        <fieldset id="HeightWeight">
                                Please provide your height and weight so that we may calculate your bmi: <br></br>                              
                                <div id="calculator">
                                
                                <!-- Button for Metric/Standard conversion -->
                                <input id="toUS" type="button" class="btnsml" value="US" onclick="metrictous();" style="display:none;">
                                <input id="tometric" type="button" class="btnsml" value="metric" onclick="ustometric();" style="display:inline;">

                                <p id="height"></p>
                                <div id="usheight" style="display:inline;">
                                    <c>Height:</c>
                                <input type="text" name="ft" id="ft" size="1" maxlength="1" onkeyup="updateBMI();" value="0">
                                    <c>ft</c> <br></br>
                                <input type="text" name="in" id="in" size="2" maxlength="2" onkeyup="updateBMI();" value="0">
                                    <c>in</c>
                                </div>
                                <div id="metricheight" style="display:none;">
                                    <c>Height:</c>
                                <input type="text" name="cm" id="cm" size="3" maxlength="3" onkeyup="updateBMI();" value="0">
                                    <c>cm</c>
                                    </div>
                                <br></br>
                                <p id="weight"></p>
                                <div id="usweight" style="display:inline;">
                                    <label for="lbs"><c>Weight:</c></label>
                                <input type="text" name="lbs" id="lbs" size="3" maxlength="3" onkeyup="updateBMI();" value="0">
                                    <c>lbs</c>
                                          </div>

                                <div id="metricweight" style="display:none;">
                                    <label for="kg"><c>Weight:</c></label>
                                <input type="text" name="kg" id="kg" size="3" maxlength="3" onkeyup="updateBMI();" value="0">
                                    <c>kg</c>
                                    </div>
                                    <br></br>
                                <p></p>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                <br></br> Thank you! 

                        </fieldset>

                        <br></br>
                        
                        <input type="hidden" value="<?=$user?>" name="user"/>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>

                        </form>

</h6>

</body>
</html>
```

So general flow is: initUser.php (calls databaseAdaptor), quiz.php, demographic.php, addUser.php (calls databaseAdaptor). All information in the database up to addUser.php seems correct.

Comment: Try checking for [PDO errors](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php)

Comment: Can you show us the code where you call `initUser()`?

Comment: Sure, I'll throw it into the main post

Comment: Something is happening... catching your errors may help illuminate what that something is.

Answer (score 1):

You are fetching your `$userId` incorrectly on the page you call `updateUser()`.

You are calling it as:

```
$user = $_GET["user"];
```

But your form is using `$_POST`, which means `$user` is being set to `NULL`. This means that nothing will happen during execution of your script because the query ***does*** successfully execute, there is just no column that has `user_id` as `NULL`. so you should be calling it via:

```
$user = $_POST["user"];
```

Which will make it equal to whatever was submitted via your form.

---

### Troubleshooting

You seem to still be having some issues. Here are some recommendations:

Use PDO differently. Try to pass all the variables via `execute()` and include `<pre>` tags to help you figure out what is going wrong. I also added a `die()` so that it will kill the page when it hits this function, so you can actually get the `<pre>` display, this should be removed after troubleshooting.

```
public function updateUser($user, $age, $gender, $height, $weight){
    $stmt = $this->DB->prepare("UPDATE users SET age=?, gender=?, height_cm=?, weight_kg=? WHERE user_id=?");

    $variables = [$age, $gender, $height, $weight, $user];
    echo "<pre>".print_r($variables, true)."</pre>";

    $stmt->execute($variables);
    return $user;
}
```

Comment: Part of the problem that I was having was that the user wasn't posting correctly from the quiz page because of a redirect to the demographic page, so it was moved to a parameter in the URL.

Comment: @JFinder What does the `updateUser()` function actually return? Can you echo it and tell me?

Comment: @JFinder Also, can you show me how you are actually accessing `addUser.php`? In the form I see it goes to `quiz.php`.

Comment: Unfortunately, updateUser() isn't returning at all, which is where I'm getting stuck. 
The rest of the information has been added to the original post.

Comment: @JFinder That means `$user` is not set, which means `$_GET['user']` is not valid.

Comment: I've moved back to $_POST and altered the form to include it as a hidden value to no effect. I can echo $user and I get the right value, but updateUser() is still refusing to run. 
Sorry, I'm still very new to this. Is it likely that is still where the issue is?

Comment: @JFinder Can you join me here so we can discuss this more without piling on comments? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163900/grumpy-programs